# How to check if any or all of gridview column values exists in a Datatable

Tags: c#

I have a Datatable that consists of more than 1000 record and a gridview that contains multiple records.I want to check if values present in grid view column  for ex:- "AID" exists in datatable's AID column values. If any value of the gridview AID exists in Datatable AID i want to set a bool flag to true if no value exists in Datatable then to false.I want to check all values at a time, not one by one using for loop etc.I have tried the folowing code

```
List<string> lstInvdiscItem = (from row in dtinv.AsEnumerable()
                                    select Convert.ToString(row["AID"])).ToList();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GrdItDetail.Rows)
{
    string invdiscitem = row.Cells["AID"].Value.ToString();
    int result = dtinv.Rows.IndexOf(dtinv.AsEnumerable().Where(g => g.Field<String>(0) == invdiscitem).FirstOrDefault());

    if (result >= 0)
    {
        DiscFlag = true;
    }
}
```

But above code checks one value at a time.My requirement is to check all values at a time just as we do using "IN" clause in sqlserver. 
How can I achieve this task using c#.Any ideas? Any suggestions?

Comment: Internally, _any_ search will go over all results (up to the point where something is found) anyway; there is never a way to get an instant result. The only thing you can do to optimize that is prefetch your DB information so you only have to do one database call, and then search purely inside the fetched results.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is to loop through the database rows and check for each AID value there whether it is in your datagrid data. (That would traverse the data table only once; traversing the datagrid or its model is probably very fast in comparison, so it can be done multiple times).